# How to define the button to play Z if Y is already playing?

Tags: android, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer

the idea is that i have 1 button and 2 states.
1. On press is playing sound Z (from a random sound list)
2. On second press: if Z.isPlaying play Y
All seems fine, till i press it 3 times in a row, and get a **nullpointerexception**

Here is the onClick code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.goat) {
            if(Piciu != null) {
                if(mp2.isPlaying()){mp2.stop();mp2.reset();mp2.release();mp2 = null;}
           butGoat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goat96);
            mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cow);
            mp3.start();
            butGoat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goat96);
            mp3.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
              public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp3) {
                butGoat.destroyDrawingCache();
                butGoat.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clipeala);
                yourAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) butGoat.getBackground();
                yourAnimation.start();  
                 Piciu = null;
              }
              });
              toast.setText("I can`t yell so Fast!");
              toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
              toast.show();
            } else {
                Piciu = mp2;
        butGoat.destroyDrawingCache();
        butGoat.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goat96);
        Random r = new Random();
         int Low = 0;
         int High = 16;
         int rndm = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low; 
         mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),sounds[rndm]);
                mp2.start();
                mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp2) {
                    butGoat.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.clipeala);
                    yourAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) butGoat.getBackground();
                    yourAnimation.start(); 
                     mp2.reset();
                     mp2.release();
                     mp2 = null;
                     Piciu = null;
                }
            }); 
              } 
           }
        }
```

i just can't understand Why do i get nullpointerexception if Sound Z is not playing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you didn't check for mp2 != null before calling mp2.isPlaying():

```
    if (view.getId() == R.id.goat) {
        if(Piciu != null) {
            if(mp2.isPlaying()){mp2.stop();mp2.reset();mp2.release();mp2 = null;}
```

change it to if (Piciu != null && mp2 != null)  Also not sure why you need the Piciu variable at all.  I'd clear up the logic first, then cleanup the code if it's still crashing.

Comment: ok it works, even if i tried this before without Piciu.
Can you tell me if the "!=" means "is" ?

Comment: != means "is not equals to" == means "is equals to"